# In Frozen Synapse, why is my score for a match I've won sometimes negative?

Tags: frozen-synapse

For about half of the matches I've won, the score listed on my match history is negative.  Did I actually lose points for these matches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't lose points, a negative score actually means points were awarded for player 2.

Score of 60 means player 1 got 60 points.

A score of -30 means player 2 got 30 points.